MacBook Pro M3 Sonoma creates many disks
I am a long-term user of MacBooks / macOS, and I never experienced this many generated disks, not created by me. How concerning is that?
Here is the output of the diskutil list:
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:             Apple_APFS_ISC Container disk1         524.3 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         494.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:        Apple_APFS_Recovery Container disk2         5.4 GB     disk0s3

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +494.4 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            13.2 GB    disk3s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 13.2 GB    disk3s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 12.3 GB    disk3s2
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.9 GB     disk3s3
   5:                APFS Volume Data                    254.6 GB   disk3s5
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk3s6

And this is the snapshot from Disk Utility:


Not concerning at all. Apple Silicon Macs are very different internally to Intel based machines, and some of this layout was present for APFS based systems on Intel too. It must be a very long time since you've seen the output from diskutil list.
Some light reading from Howard Oakley especially this page on the transition from Mojave to M chips which deals specifically with the disk changes.

Looks horrid after a long time of Intels use. There you had only Macintosh HD and Data; here, it looks like a contagion...  Thanks for the reassuring words Andy Griffiths!

@striatum You would have the Recovery partition and the EFI boot volume, too.
